# Selenium - Headless Chrome working on one computer and not another

Tags: python, windows, selenium, google-chrome

I have a script that I run locally that uses `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')` and `options = chrome_options` to make certain functions run in the background. It works perfectly fine on my computer. However, I had someone else run it on their computer and it did not work in headless -- it worked without it though. They have exactly the same Chrome version as I do. One difference is that I am on Windows 10 while they are using Windows 7.

Any tips on what this could be/where I should look for the issue?

Comment: Are you getting any specific error?If so then you need to post that as well?

Comment: I'm not in front of it right now, but the error is that it cannot find a certain element, which is the first element it looks for in the function.

Comment: You need to post your chrome option details?

Comment: I did. chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

Answer (score 0):

Try below code see if this work.Set the window size.
For headless browser you have to set the window size to fire any event.Because headless browser can't recognise where to click without window size.

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. The thing is it works on my computer perfectly fine (without the window-size option).